# Spring Data Couchbase Version Compatibility with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

We plan to upgrade **Spring Data Couchbase** to **5.1.0** in our Spring Boot project. However we couldn't find any information if **5.X** version is compatible with **Spring Boot 2.7.X**.

Does **Spring Data Couchbase** have any release document on compatibility and any other changes since **4.x** versions? Reference documents on **docs.spring.io** (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/) don't provide any information about this topic.

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring-data-couchbase 5.1 has a dependency on spring-boot 3.1.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/5.1.x/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks @michael for your reply. I think we could go with 4.x version with Spring Boot 2.7 then. Is there a list of changes between 4.x and 5.x?